# How to set timeout on SUDS connection

Tags: python, timeout, suds

I'm struggling with what should be a very simple problem.  I'm failing to set the session timeout on a SUDS jurko connection. My WSDL is good. Everything works when pulling a smaller dataset. I've attempted several means of setting the timeout. While the following doesn't complain/etc, it also is ineffective:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(authUrl, timeout=600)
```

My connection/etc appears to fail after the default 90 seconds. Unfortunately, this just isn't long enough to get the data I need.  The error I receive is

```
ssl.SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',)
```

Help! My Google foo is weak, I guess. I've tried many things... and, finally, I have to ask for help. Which will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: probably helpful if you include your WSDL.

Comment: The WSDL is fine. I'm successfully pulling data. The problem I'm facing is that the DEV copy pulls only ~1,000 records. The PROD copy (same WSDL, different server) pulls ~20,000 records. I'm just getting a timeout.

Unfortunately, I can't easily post the WSDL. It's on a separate machine/network/etc.

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: Sorry, folks -- I've since moved to a different project (and company). I never did find a way around this. The root cause/condition (IIRC) was that the volume of data was simply too great. I no longer have access to the code. I've mercifully been spared the horror of dealing with SOAP since that time. :-)  Good luck to the less fortunate!

Answer (score 0):

While this will not help the OP I think that it is worth mentioning that under Python 3.9 the call to `Client(...., timeout=300)` seems to be working with `sudz` version 1.0.3 from https://github.com/Skylude/suds - so I guess that this issue has been resolved.